# setting up crons in sentora website panel w.r.t Cpanel [Control Panel]

Tags: php, linux, cron, cron-task

I have installed sentora today on new CentOS 6 VPS. 
I have migrated from cpanel . and looking to set crons jobs here wrt to cpanel.

Cpanel Syntax for my crons
1:

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://www.domain.com/filename.php?pwd=11111 2 > /dev/null
```

where  pwd=11111  is password set for that cron file to be run only from script.
2:

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://www.domain.com/filename.php 2 > /dev/null
```

This is the syntax of all cron in cpanel.

I am writing these lines in sentora to set up crons. But every time I receive this error.

Error: Your script does not appear to exist at that location.

My crons for sentora.

this one does not work:

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent Site_Dir/filename.php  2 > /dev/null
```

This one works:

```
Site_Dir/filename.php
```

As per sentora documentation:
**example: /folder/task.php 

Note 1 : Script path is relative to your sentora-user root directory:

  /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/ 

Note 2 : Each file access in your script must use absolute directory path as above.**

I dont know how to set up crons for password protected files.
I need to confirm this before moving my website to new server. And there is no other way to confirm the working of cron but after site migration.

Kindly extend you support on this issue

I know A lots of users will be facing the same issue who has migrated from cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

As per a 'How-To' post on the forums: http://forums.sentora.org/showthread.php?tid=491&pid=6072#pid6072

> If arguments need to be passed that do NOT change, simply make a small
>   php file with an include statement like below and call this new cron file instead.

Example new_cron.php:

```
<?php
include('Site_Dir/filename.php?foo=xxx&bar=xxx');
?>
```